# want to add variables and hardcoded values to json before comparing

Tags: java, json, string

in my case, I am getting a json in which I need to modify the timestamp of today and then need to add some specific time (hardcoded), I'm trying it but everytime my json gets messed up.

Here is the json I'm getting -

```
{"offerId":"00000002","offerStatus":"A","startDate":"2023-01-13T00:00:00-05:00"}
```

I want to change the time of the start date is like this 2023-01-16T00:00:00-05:00 -- I used java.time.LocalDate.now().toString() function, but it only gives me the date, I want to add timezone hardcoded,

I tried this but it didn't work -

```
String expected = "{\"offerId\":\"00000002\",\"offerStatus\":\"A\",\"startDate\":"\""+java.time.LocalDate.now().toString()+"T00:00:00-05:00\"};
```

how can I achieve that? thanks!

Comment: First of all, have you tried mapping the JSON to a POJO with for example Jackson? It has methods to convert string to POJO and back after you've modified the date.
Also, you can use `ZonedDateTime` for times with timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ZonedDateTime` where you can pass your own zone offset.
Example: `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString()`